# how can i parsing some string which i want use bs4?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

this is html architecture

```
<a href="/main/list.nhn?mode=LS2D&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;sid2=264" class="snb_s11 nclicks(lmn_pol.mnl,,1)">BlueHouse <span class="blind">selected</span></a>
```

and then below is my source code to get only Blue House

```py
 middle_category = soup.find('a',{'class':'snb_s11 nclicks(lmn_pol.mnl,,1)'})
```

**when i run that code to get only Blue House, it's gave me result with selected.**

### but i wanna only Blue House. so How can i do for it?

bellow is my full code

```
    def crwaling_data_bluehouse(self):
        # setting web driver to get object
        chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/바탕 화면/인턴/python/crawling_software/crwaler/news_crwaling/chromedriver.exe')
        url = 'https://news.naver.com/main/list.nhn?mode=LS2D&mid=shm&sid1=100&sid2=264'
        chrome_driver.get(url)
        html = chrome_driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        
        #get main category
        main_category = soup.find('a',{'class':'nclicks(LNB.pol)'}).find('span',{'class':'tx'}).get_text()
        self.set_main_category(main_category)
        
        #get middle category
        middle_category = soup.find('a',{'class':'snb_s11 nclicks(lmn_pol.mnl,,1)'}).get_text()
        middle_category = middle_category.find_next(text = True)
        self.set_middle_category(middle_category)
        
        #get title
        title = soup.find('ul',{'class':'type06_headline'}).find('a')['href']
        self.set_title(title)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) which will only return the first match:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """<a href="/main/list.nhn?mode=LS2D&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;sid2=264" class="snb_s11 nclicks(lmn_pol.mnl,,1)">BlueHouse <span class="blind">selected</span></a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

middle_category = soup.find('a', {'class': 'snb_s11 nclicks(lmn_pol.mnl,,1)'})
print(middle_category.find_next(text=True))
```

Output:

```
BlueHouse
```

**Edit** don't call `get_text()`. Instead of

`middle_category = soup.find('a',{'class':'snb_s11 nclicks(lmn_pol.mnl,,1)'}).get_text()`

Use `middle_category = soup.find('a', {'class': 'snb_s11 nclicks(lmn_pol.mnl,,1)'}).find_next(text=True)`

Comment: when i was use find_next() as like you, i get a AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_next'.

Comment: @YangDongJae please edit the code in your original question post

Comment: I'm not used to it yet. and i edit to my original code!

Comment: @YangDongJae See my edit. Don't call `get_text()`, since you will get a `str` and not a `beautifulsoup` object

Comment: jesus! i solved this problem. thank you for your help. Do i become as like you?