# Beautiful Soup, get_text but NOT the <span> text.. How can i get it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mysql-python

Given this markup:
[MARKUP][1]

I need to get the number **182** in a column and the  **58** in another. I **already have the span**, but when I call the **div.get_tex() or string** it returns = **18258**(both numbers)

This is my code_:

```
prices= soup.find_all('div', class_='grilla-producto-precio')

cents= []
price= []
for px in prices:
    ### here i need to get the number 182 and append it to "price"
    for spn in px.find('span'):
        cents.append(spn)
```

HOW CAN I GET THE PRICE 182 ALONE WITHOUT THE SPAN? THANKS!!!!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld9qo.png

Comment: `cents.append(spn.text)`?

Comment: someone helped me, but the comment was erased.. it was div.find_next(text=True)

Comment: Yeah it was me. Check out my answer.

Comment: I could get it only with the text=true, didn't need to do the split and replace

Comment: If u use split and replace, then u can get just the number that u want. Plus, u can also get it as an int.

Comment: try `soup.select_one(".grilla-producto-precio").contents[0]` or `soup.select_one(".grilla-producto-precio").next_element` and then use replace and strip to get the required portion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is almost the same as the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64329368/how-can-i-parsing-some-string-which-i-want-use-bs4).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class = "grilla-producto-precio">
" $"
"182"
<span>58</span>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

prices = soup.find_all('div',class_ = "grilla-producto-precio")

cents = []

for px in prices:
    txt = px.find_next(text=True).strip()

    txt = txt.replace('"','')

    txt = int(txt.split("\n")[-1])
    
    cents.append(txt)
```

Output:

```
[182]
```

Comment: It appears to be a duplicate answer :) Can you link them with mark duplicate? +1

Comment: Sure. But before that, is this ques an exact duplicate? It was just related to the link that I mentioned. But anyways, if u feel that it is a duplicate, then I will mark it as a duplicate. Experienced people are always right!

Comment: No, problem. I have updated it with simpler and robust. The `int()` will fail if the incoming data not numeric.

Comment: Bummer no, it is not span s/he wants. I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to check if the string [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """
<div class = "grilla-producto-precio">
" $"
"182"
<span>58</span>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

data = soup.find("div", class_="grilla-producto-precio").next
price = [int("".join(d for d in data if d.isdigit()))]

print(price) # Output: [182]
```